# Is the geofencing module broken on appcelerator? is there an alternative?

Tags: module, appcelerator, geofencing, appcelerator-modules

I just upgraded to one of the premium memberships so that I could use the geofencing module. I'm having no luck at all, and there is no help from appcelerator.

Here is my simple, simple code:

```
var geoFences = e.geo_fences;
var regionList = [ ];
var region = Geofence.createRegion( {
  center: {
    latitude: 26,
    longitude: -98
  },
  radius: 400,
  identifier: 'test'
} );
regionList.push( region );

// There are multiple events tested here, because the sample code
// on appcelerators docs say "enterregion", but the list
// of events for the object says "enterregions"

Geofence.addEventListener( "enterregions", function( e ) {
  Ti.API.info('enter region fired');
});
Geofence.addEventListener( "enterregion", function( e ) {
  Ti.API.info('enter regions fired');
});
Geofence.addEventListener( "exitregion", function( e ) {
  Ti.API.info('exit region fired');
});
Geofence.addEventListener( "exitregions", function( e ) {
  Ti.API.info('exit regions fired');
});
Geofence.addEventListener( "error", function( e ) {
  Ti.API.info('error fired');
});
Geofence.addEventListener( "monitorregions", function( e ) {
  Ti.API.info('monitor regions fired');
});

// Start monitoring for region entrances/exits:
Geofence.startMonitoringForRegions( regionList );
```

I open the app in the iOS simulator, and i see:
[INFO] :   monitor regions fired

So it's monitoring the region. But i go to Debug > Location > Custom Location, and set it to 25, -98 (out of the region) then to 26, -98 (in the center of the region), then back to 25, -98, and I don't get any of the enter or exit regions firing!

I also tried this with a more precise location on an iphone 6+ with live cell and gps enabled. I drove from 1 mile away to the exact location, and it did not fire any of the events (400m is approx 1/4 mile)

I can't test it on android because there is a build error that i'm currently working on with appcelerator in jira.

Is the module broken? Is there an alternative module?

Comment: You do actually define regions to monitor I assume?

Answer (score 0):

I use the module myself, very successfully. So it does work.

Comment: it seems after lots of rebuilding and resetting, the same code finally works - but only in the simulator. in an actual device it still doesn't work. is it possible that it's got something to do with the developer profile? i deleted the app, rebooted the phone, reinstalled the app, made sure it had permission to always access my location, etc - but no events are fired

Comment: I have never had a problem with it on a device. The only thing is making sure that you have location permissions set. And make sure you are setting a Geo fence that works for you.

Ray